# Could not load file or assembly 'log4net'

Tags: log4net

My crystal report page gives an error "Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference."
Do I have to have ddl for 1.2.10 or 1.2.11 in bin folder? Or what can be wrong?

Comment: Where do you currently have the log4net dll located?  Is this a web application?  How do you have log4net referenced in your visual studio project?  I've seen this error before if you have it referenced from the GAC on the development machine but not installed in the GAC on the production machine.

Comment: it is a web application. we don't want to load sap object for crystal report to server. we only put dll's to bin directory. please suggest a solution on this way.

Comment: there are two flavros of log4net 1.5.10 (and 11, etc) that used different dll keys... download the verison of 11 and map to use that one in the web.config

Answer (score 1):

If you have a x86 development machine and your web server is a 64-bit machine, you may be running into the problem [discussed in this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vscrystalreports/thread/546059a6-7179-4027-8f16-822ac6dc189a/).

Visual Studio is automatically deploying a 32-bit log4net.dll into the 64-bit web server, even if you don't have it referenced in your project. Just delete the log4net.dll from your bin directory once deployment has finished because it's not actually required by the CR runtime to work.